# Specifying multiple columns names with the same prefix efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I am running a regression with my observation being at the company level. I want to control for the type of company [what does it produce]. I have this information in an object variable which I turn into categorical and then get the dummies out of it.

```
df['Product Type'] = df['Product Type'].astype('category')
df =  pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Product Type']).head()
```

My sample is quite large and I end up getting a lot of dummy variables. It is quite a lot of work to introduce them into my model one by one (there might be 10-15 of them).

```
reg = sm.OLS(endog=df['Y'], exog= df[['X1', 'Number of workers', 'X2', "Product Type_Jewellery", "Product_Type_Apparel", (all the other product dummies) ]], missing='drop')
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? In stata, I used the prefix i.Product_Type which would signal to the software that the String variable had to be considered as a categorical one... anything similar?

Comment: Since you mention stata, you need to be very explicit with `statsmodels`. With your current `OLS` function you do not have an intercept term, and you will use the complete set of categories. Stata would typically include the intercept and instead drop one of the categories as the reference category.

Comment: thanks so much, i was not aware of it, how do I let statsmodel calculate the intercept?

Comment: The simplest way is to add a column of all `1` called `'intercept'` to exog, something like `subset.assign(intercept=1)` will work in coldspeed's solution. But then you run into an issue of collinearity, so you need to manually drop one of the product categories yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.contains` to find the columns that contain "Product_*", and accessing them becomes easy.

```
c = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Product')]
```

If regex is not needed, you can initialise `c` as

```
c = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Product', regex=False)]
```

Or, using `str.startswith`:

```
c = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Product')]
```

Or, a list comprehension:

```
c = [c_ for c_ in df if c_.startswith('Product')]
```

---

Finally, access the subset by unpacking `c`:

```
subset = df[['X1', 'Number of workers', 'X2', *c]]
reg = sm.OLS(endog=df['Y'], exog=subset, missing='drop')
```

Answer (score 2):

Same idea like what cold provided by using `filter`

```
sm.OLS(endog=df['Y'], 
       exog=df.filter(regex=r'X1|X2|Number|Product'), 
       missing='drop')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `statsmodels.formula.api` you don't need to generate the dummies yourself. Remove spaces from you column names and reference the Categorical column with `C(col_name)`

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df = df.rename(columns={'Product Type': 'Product_Type',
                        'Number of workers': 'Number_of_workers'})

results = smf.ols(formula = 'Y ~ X1 + X2 + Number_of_workers + C(Product_Type)', 
                  data=df, missing='drop').fit()
```

---

Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Y': np.random.randint(1,100,200),
                   'X1': np.random.normal(1,20,200),
                   'X2': np.random.normal(-10,1,200),
                   'Number of workers': np.arange(1,201,1)/10,
                   'Product Type': np.random.choice(list('abcde'), 200)})
```

Output of `results.summary()`

```
========================================================================================
                           coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept               69.2836     23.105      2.999      0.003      23.711     114.856
C(Product_Type)[T.b]    11.3334      6.941      1.633      0.104      -2.356      25.023
C(Product_Type)[T.c]     1.3745      6.943      0.198      0.843     -12.321      15.070
C(Product_Type)[T.d]     2.0430      6.258      0.326      0.744     -10.300      14.386
C(Product_Type)[T.e]     3.8445      6.273      0.613      0.541      -8.528      16.217
X1                       0.0207      0.113      0.184      0.854      -0.202       0.243
X2                       1.4677      2.177      0.674      0.501      -2.825       5.761
Number_of_workers       -0.5803      0.369     -1.573      0.117      -1.308       0.147
==============================================================================
```

Notice, that with the formulas api since your `products` create a complete basis it will automatically drop one of the categories since we have the intercept, similar to what you would find in stata.